# fecha.js - date / time, specific time of day

Tags: javascript, date, parsing

Trying to use fecha.js 
https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha 
to get a specific time of day each day. (so only specify time, not date)

specifically looking to 3pm PST (6 EST) each day...

I am trying:

```
fecha.format(new Date(03, 00), 'h:mm');
```

and it's returning: 12:00

is there a way to get this to work? and also use a specific time, like EST, or pull from UTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not use the [constructor parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) of `Date` properly:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hour, ...);
```

Your code should be:

```
fecha.format(new Date(0, 0, 0, 03, 00), 'h:mm');
```

Then it [will work](https://jsfiddle.net/y7f719td/)!

Comment: Tim, thanks that works perfectly, is there a way for it to be  an official time like UTC< or EST< than the user's system time?

Comment: @M21, It already is: `Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC`. If you need to be sure that time is right, you will need to use a server.

Comment: thanks so much. Now if I can figure out how to get it into my countdown I'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mydate = new Date(); mydate.setHours(3); mydate.setMinutes(0);
fecha.format(mydate, 'h:mm');
```